# how to install social login cartridges for Salesforce Commerce Cloud B2C?"

Tags: lightning-web-components, b2c, salesfront-reference-architecture

I'm a beginner in Salesforce. basically, i want to know how to install social login cartridges like Facebook login, google login and how to display their icon on the storefront.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question, but as a beginner, there is a complete guide made by Salesforce to get started - including how to build custom features and configure standard ones.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/commerce/sfra/guide/sfra-learn-more.html

Module 1: Kickoff - https://share.vidyard.com/watch/Fb8F2oEzjmhTigF73rQPLD

Module 2: Cartridges and Controllers - https://share.vidyard.com/watch/ASVVEWfhkJ2uPDeoxbosL3

Module 3: Models, ISML, and Client-Side JavaScript -  https://share.vidyard.com/watch/zwNXrskJgzysXJZo7CNaC5

Module 4: Forms, Transactions, and Middleware Events - https://share.vidyard.com/watch/XdAJam3xCAMQ7UYrAVxSwW

Module 5: Page Designer and Job Framework - https://share.vidyard.com/watch/j29VTc9BbqpyH7kkrubW2k

Module 6: OCAPI and Web Service Framework - https://share.vidyard.com/watch/JUR9eco8noLmS11dQA1CKt